# Please Report: Excessing number of pending callbacks - React Native Socket.io client

Tags: react-native, socket.io

```
const [markets,setMarkets]=useState(false)
 useEffect(() => {
    if (socketConnection != null) {
      socketConnection.on("url", (data) => {
        getData();
        markets.length > 0 &&
          markets.map((market) => {
            if (data.pair == market.pair) {
              let newPrice = data.price.toFixed(data.decimalValue);
              let oldData = markets.filter(
                (market) => market.pair == data.pair
              )[0];
              let oldIndex = markets.findIndex(
                (market) => market.pair == data.pair
              );
              let oldPrice = oldData.price.toFixed(oldData.decimalValue);
              if (newPrice != oldPrice) {
                markets[oldIndex].price = data.price;
                markets[oldIndex].lastPrice = data.lastPrice;
                markets[oldIndex].change = data.change;
                markets[oldIndex].oldPrice = oldData.price;
              }
            }
          });
      });
     setMarkets(markets);
    }
  }, [socketConnection]);
```

I am updating my state like this using socket.io-client but getting this error as Please Report : Excessive number of pending requests and app is hanged.Anyone plse help for the issue